# Unable to boot from USB drive; boot configuration for pc is missing or damaged

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, slackware, usb-boot, lilo

When I tried to install slackware on my pc (Dell optiplex 780   with a Kingston 240gb ssd  and a Hitachi 250gb hdd), along with windows 10, I got an installation error. Lilo Linux wasn't able to install. I tried to install it in the master boot record. When I restarted the pc,  Windows wouldn't boot:

```
File: \Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc000000f
Info: The boot configuration data for your pc is missing or contains errors.
```

I got prompted to insert a Windows installation disk and restart the computer. I don't have a Windows cd, so I made one using rufus and the media creation tool provided by Windows (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO). When I put the drive in the pc, the pc did not boot from the USB drive. The drive was detected however, but the pc froze at this screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST06J.jpg]

Nothing happens when I have press enter. I can access the system setup menu or the on-board diagnostics. There are no important files on the drives. 
What can I do to fix this problem?